# How to tell if I've already processed a node

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I am processing large files consisting of many redundant values (using YAML's anchors and references). The processing I do on each structure is expensive, and I would like to detect whether I'm looking at a reference to an anchor I've already processed. In Python (with python-yaml), I did this by simply building a dictionary keyed by id(node). Since yaml-cpp uses Node as a reference type, however, this does not seem to work here. Any suggestions?

This is similar to [Retrieve anchor & alias string in yaml-cpp from document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638802/retrieve-anchor-alias-string-in-yaml-cpp-from-document), but although that feature would be sufficient to solve my problem, it is not neccessary -- if I could get somehow a hash based on the internal address of the node, for example, that would be fine.

The expensive thing I'm doing is computing a hash of each node including itself and its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a patch that seems to do what I need. Proceed with caution.

```
diff -nr include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node.h new/yaml-cpp-0.5.1/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node.h
a13 1
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
a24 1
            std::size_t identity_hash() const { return boost::hash<node_ref*>()(m_pRef.get()); }
diff -nr /include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h new/yaml-cpp-0.5.1/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h
a175 5
    inline std::size_t Node::identity_hash() const
    {
    return m_pNode->identity_hash();
    }

diff -nr include/yaml-cpp/node/node.h new/yaml-cpp-0.5.1/include/yaml-cpp/node/node.h
a55 2
        std::size_t identity_hash() const;
```

I can then use the below to make a unordered_map using YAML::Node as key.

```
namespace std {
  template <>
  struct hash<YAML::Node> {
    size_t operator()(const YAML::Node& ss) const {
      return ss.identity_hash();
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check node identity by `operator ==` or `Node::is`, e.g.:

```
Node a = ...;
process(a);
Node b = ...;
if (!a.is(b)) {
  process(b);
}
```

I suppose this isn't perfect - if you're trying to do this on a large list of nodes, the checking will have to be O(n).

If you want more than this, please file an issue on the project page.

Comment: What I really need is a way to specialize std::hash so I can use an unordered_map, so unfortunately pairwise equality won't do much.